# Updating using subqueries sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

There are two update queries and 1st update query execute successfully but 2nd update query is not execute and show the following message:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

1st update query:

```
update dbo.TblPrePostApproval 
set 
    dbo.TblPrePostApproval.PAApprovedDate = (select dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppRefDate 
                                             from dbo.TblMasterInfo 
                                             Where dbo.TblMasterInfo.Appid = dbo.TblPrePostApproval.Appid),
    dbo.TblPrePostApproval.PAApprovedTenor = '36',
    dbo.TblPrePostApproval.PAApprovedAmt = (select dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppReqeustAmt 
                                            from dbo.TblMasterInfo 
                                            where dbo.TblPrePostApproval.Appid = dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppID),  
    dbo.TblPrePostApproval.PADisbBr = (select dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppSourceBrName 
                                       from dbo.TblMasterInfo 
                                       where dbo.TblPrePostApproval.Appid = dbo.TblMasterInfo.AppID)
```

2nd update query

```
update dbo.TblPrePostApproval   
set 
   dbo.TblPrePostApproval.PAApprovedDate = (select dbo.TestPost.PADate 
                                            from dbo.TestPost 
                                            Where dbo.TestPost.Appid = dbo.TblPrePostApproval.Appid),
   dbo.TblPrePostApproval.PAApprovedTenor = (select dbo.TestPost.PATenor 
                                             from dbo.TestPost 
                                             Where dbo.TestPost.Appid = dbo.TblPrePostApproval.Appid),
   dbo.TblPrePostApproval.PAApprovedAmt = (select dbo.TestPost.PAAmt 
                                           from dbo.TestPost 
                                           where dbo.TestPost.Appid = dbo.TblPrePostApproval.AppID),    
   dbo.TblPrePostApproval.PADisbBr = (select dbo.TestPost.PABr 
                                      from dbo.TestPost 
                                      where dbo.TestPost.Appid = dbo.TblPrePostApproval.AppID)
```

Where is my problem? Pls any one suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your subqueries (I guess on line 10) is returning more than one row, so it can't check to see if it equals anything, because it's a set, not a value. Just change your query to be more specific. Try adding `LIMIT 0, 1` to the end of the subqueries, or `TOP (1)` after the the `SELECT` in each subquery.

Comment: My update query is right but I more than one raw was available into both table. I solve my problem with correction these table raw. Thanks Mr. golgothan3

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `JOIN`s for your update? Much easier to read and understand!

Query #1:

```
UPDATE ppa
SET
    PAApprovedDate = info.AppRefDate,
    PAApprovedTenor = '36',
    PAApprovedAmt = info.AppReqeustAmt,
    PADisbBr = info.AppSourceBrName 
FROM
    dbo.TblPrePostApproval ppa
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TblMasterInfo.TblMasterInfo info ON info.Appid = ppa.Appid
```

Query #2:

```
UPDATE ppa
SET
   PAApprovedDate = tp.PADate,
   PAApprovedTenor = tp.PATenor,
   PAApprovedAmt = tp.PAAmt,    
   PADisbBr = tp.PABr
FROM
    dbo.TblPrePostApproval ppa
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TestPost tp ON tp.Appid = ppa.AppID
```

Comment: My update query is right but I more than one raw was available into both table. I solve my problem with correction these table raw